# how to use JRadioButton groups with a model

Tags: java, swing, radio-button, jradiobutton

Is there any way to associate a group of JRadioButtons with a data model so it is easier to tell which button (if any) is selected?

In an ideal world, I would like to associate a group of N radiobuttons with an `enum` class that has a `NONE` value and one value associated with each radiobutton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my own problem, this wasn't too hard, so share and enjoy:

```
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class RadioButtonGroupEnumAdapter<E extends Enum<E>> {
    final private Map<E, JRadioButton> buttonMap;

    public RadioButtonGroupEnumAdapter(Class<E> enumClass)
    {
        this.buttonMap = new EnumMap<E, JRadioButton>(enumClass);
    }
    public void importMap(Map<E, JRadioButton> map)
    {
        for (E e : map.keySet())
        {
            this.buttonMap.put(e, map.get(e));
        }
    }
    public void associate(E e, JRadioButton btn)
    {
        this.buttonMap.put(e, btn);
    }
    public E getValue()
    {
        for (E e : this.buttonMap.keySet())
        {
            JRadioButton btn = this.buttonMap.get(e);
            if (btn.isSelected())
            {
                return e;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    public void setValue(E e)
    {
        JRadioButton btn = (e == null) ? null : this.buttonMap.get(e);
        if (btn == null)
        {
            // the following doesn't seem efficient...
                    // but since when do we have more than say 10 radiobuttons?
            for (JRadioButton b : this.buttonMap.values())
            {
                b.setSelected(false);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            btn.setSelected(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about to use [EnumMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html)?

Comment: I don't understand your question; I did use EnumMap.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `javax.swing.ButtonGroup` on the lines of what you're looking for

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html

Comment: no, because it deals with ButtonModels. I want a single model that deals with enum values.