# Synchronize radio buttons and radio groups

Tags: java, swing, events, radio-button, radio-group

How do I synchronize different radio buttons, on different windows, that means the same. Like:

Window `A` (main): `radioButtonA1`, `radioButtonA2` (both in `radioGroupA`)

Window `B` (popup): `radioButtonB1`, `radioButtonB2` (both in `radioGroupB`)

...where `radioButtonA1` means the same that `radioButtonB1`, and `radioButtonA2` means the same that `radioButtonB2` (like of they were mirrored).

When I change the radio selections via `itemStateChanged`, I want also to synchronize the selection display. So if I change the selection in `radioGroupA` to `radioButtonA2`, I want that `radioGroupB` also changes it selection to `radioButtonB2` (as they mean the same).

But I want that the event `itemStateChanged` on both radio buttons be called only **once**. If I tell `radioButtonA2` `itemStateChanged` event to also adjust the selection of `radioGroupB` to `radioButtonB2`, then the `radioButtonB2` `itemStateChanged` event will also be fired (or vice-versa), and I don't want that.

Independent, if I pressed `radioButtonA2` or `radioButtonB2`, I want the display to be synchronized and then call the method i wrote to deal with the change. But only once, not twice.  Any help?

Comment: `Any help?` yes could be based on your code, for better help post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short runnable, compilable, just about a.m. issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for sort of an MVC approach: you have 1 model object, which is represented by multiple views (in multiple windows in your case).

You could use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059122/how-to-use-jradiobutton-groups-with-a-model) to be the model of your radiogroup.

Comment: Thanks, your answer guided me to the right path. It worked pretty fine.